# Mailchimp conditional merge tags - to use conditional date logic based on today

Tags: merge, tags, conditional-statements, mailchimp, mailmerge

I am using a date token, which is filled in a signup form. I would like to do conditional logic, based on whether the date is less than 2 weeks away from today.  I would like to do something like the below

```
*|IF:CHECKINDATE<TODAY+20DAYS|*
This is the code for your accommodation: 123456789
*|END:IF|*
```

Do you know if it is possible?